# How to fix error exception to make script restart

Tags: python, discord.py

I have a Discord Python3.6 bot that uses a website's API to pull items from the website and push them into my Discord server. I have just been having a few errors with it. It works fine sometimes and will update every 5 minutes like I specified, but after around 10 or so updates it crashes. I want it to be able to ignore this error and restart when it crashes so I don't have to manually do it. I will provide a picture of the scenario.

I had hired someone to make this bot for me awhile back and I've since lost contact with them, I have a very small knowledge of Python so I haven't been able to try much.

There are two files, this is the one that does all of the API stuff and the other one does the Discord related stuff. This one is called bitskins.py

```
#!/bin/python3.5
import requests
import json
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

class Item:
    def __init__(self, item):
        withdrawable_at= item['withdrawable_at']
        price= float(item['price'])
        self.available_in= withdrawable_at- datetime.timestamp(datetime.now())
        if self.available_in< 0:
            self.available= True
        else:
            self.available= False
        self.suggested_price= float(item['suggested_price'])
        self.price= price
        self.margin= round(self.suggested_price- self.price, 2)
        self.reduction= round((1- (self.price/self.suggested_price))*100, 2)
        self.image= item['image']
        self.name= item['market_hash_name']
        self.item_id= item['item_id']

    def __str__(self):
        if self.available:
            return "Name: {}\nPrice: {}\nSuggested Price: {}\nReduction: {}%\nAvailable Now !\nLink: https://bitskins.com/view_item?app_id=730&item_id={}".format(self.name, self.price, self.suggested_price, self.reduction, self.item_id)
        else:
            return "Name: {}\nPrice: {}\nSuggested Price: {}\nReduction: {}%\nAvailable in: {}\nLink: https://bitskins.com/view_item?app_id=730&item_id={}".format(self.name, self.price, self.suggested_price, self.reduction, str(timedelta(seconds= self.available_in)), self.item_id)

    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self.reduction < other.reduction
    def __gt__(self, other):
        return self.reduction > other.reduction


def get_url(API_KEY, code):
    PER_PAGE= 30 # the number of items to retrieve. goes from 30 to 480
    return "https://bitskins.com/api/v1/get_inventory_on_sale/?api_key="+ API_KEY+"&code=" + code+ "&per_page="+ str(PER_PAGE)

def get_data(url):
    r= requests.get(url)
    data= r.json()
    return data

def get_items(code, API_KEY):
    url= get_url(API_KEY, code)
    try:
        data= get_data(url)
        if data['status']=="success":
            items= []
            items_dic= data['data']['items']
            for item in items_dic:
                tmp= Item(item)
                if tmp.reduction>=20:
                    items.append(tmp)
            return items
        else:
            raise Exception(data["data"]["error_message"])
    except:
        print("Couldn't connect to Bitskins")

# my_token = pyotp.TOTP(my_secret)
# print(my_token.now()) # in python3
```

Here is the second file solution.py

```
#!/bin/python3.5
import bitskins
import discord
import pyotp, base64, asyncio
from datetime import timedelta, datetime

TOKEN= "NOT SHOWING THE BOT TOKEN"

API_KEY= "NOT SHOWING API KEY"

my_secret= 'NOT SHOWING MY SECRET KEY'

client= discord.Client()

def get_embed(item):
    embed=discord.Embed(title=item.name, url= "https://bitskins.com/view_item?app_id=730&item_id={}".format(item.item_id), color=0x75bacf)
    embed.set_author(name="Skin Bot", url="https://www.reactor.gg/",icon_url="https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/574801125765808131/ffeb4b83f75977f6a8f20c5ecb5f0164.png")
    embed.set_thumbnail(url=item.image)
    embed.add_field(name="Price :", value="${}".format(item.price))
    embed.add_field(name="Discount :" , value="{}%".format(item.reduction), inline=True)
    if item.available:
        tmp= "Instantly Withdrawable"
    else:
        tmp= str(timedelta(seconds= item.available_in))
    embed.add_field(name="Availability:", value=tmp, inline=True)
    embed.add_field(name="Suggested Price :", value="${}".format(item.suggested_price), inline=True)
    embed.add_field(name="Margin :", value="${}".format(item.margin), inline=True)
    embed.set_footer(text="Made By Stahp")
    return embed

async def status_task(wait_time= 60* 5):
    while True:
        print("Updated on: {}".format(datetime.now()))
        code= pyotp.TOTP(my_secret)
        items= bitskins.get_items(code.now(), API_KEY)
        for item in items:
            await client.send_message(client.get_channel("564815517601234953"), embed=get_embed(item))
        await asyncio.sleep(wait_time)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    wait_time= 60 * 10 # 10 mins in this case
    print("Logged in as")
    print(client.user.name)
    print(client.user.id)
    print("------")
    client.loop.create_task(status_task(wait_time))

try:
    client.run(TOKEN)
except:
    print("Couldn't connect to the Discord Server")
```

Here is the screenshot of the error I get: https://gyazo.com/7c4ba03e8a9e182bf79c625c3455dd5b

Comment: Could you include the code for `status_task`?  That's the code that's failing.

Comment: Sure, I will add it to the original post.

Answer (score 0):

If there's an exception in `get_items`, then the `except` clause doesn't return anything, which means it returns `None` implicitly.  You should return an empty list instead:

```
def get_items(code, API_KEY):
    url= get_url(API_KEY, code)
    try:
        data= get_data(url)
        if data['status']=="success":
            items= []
            items_dic= data['data']['items']
            for item in items_dic:
                tmp= Item(item)
                if tmp.reduction>=20:
                    items.append(tmp)
            return items
        else:
            raise Exception(data["data"]["error_message"])
    except Exception as e:
        print("Couldn't connect to Bitskins")
        print(e)
        return []
```

Comment: It's been up for about 2 hours now with no issues! I'll come back if I have any more problems, thank you!